# python string to list - list comprehension

Tags: python, string, list

The input is a string and the output is a list, each cell contains the corresponding word. 
Word is defined to be a sequence of letters and/or numbers.
For example, `Ilove` is a word, `45tgfd` is a word, `54fss.` isn't a word because it has `.`.

Let us assume that commas come only after a word.

For example - `'Donald John Trump, born June 14, 1946, is the 45th'`
should become 
`['Donald', 'John', 'Trump', 'born', 'June', '14', '1946', 'is', 'the', '45th']`

Tried doing it with 
`[x.rstrip(',') for x in line.split() if x.rstrip(',').isalpha() or x.rstrip(',').isdigit()]`
when line is the original string, however it became messy and wrong - couldn't detect '45th' because of `isdigit` and `isalpha`.

any idea?

Comment: For dealing with "54fss.", is the expected result that you ignore the whole thing, or just ignore the period on the end? In other words, is it only commas that get treated specially?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `str.isalnum`:

```
>>> [x for x in (s.rstrip(',') for s in line.split()) if x.isalnum()]
['Donald', 'John', 'Trump', 'born', 'June', '14', '1946', 'is', 'the', '45th']
>>>
```

Notice, too, I'm not redundantly calling `rstrip` by using a generator expression *inside* the comprehension, this also let's me do only single pass on `line.split()`.

Comment: New one to me, +1

Comment: @bernie yeah, Python string methods have a lot of hidden gems.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re

>>> s = 'Donald John Trump, born June 14, 1946, is the 45th'
>>> [i.strip(',') for i in re.split(r'\s+',s) if not re.search(r'^[\.]|\w+\.\w+|[\.]$',i)]
['Donald', 'Trump', 'born', 'June', '14', '1946', 'is', 'the', '45th']

>>> s2 = 'tes.t .test test. another word'
>>> [i.strip(',') for i in re.split(r'\s+',s2) if not re.search(r'^[\.]|\w+\.\w+|[\.]$',i)]
['another', 'word']
```

Comment: Using `re` is likely the best approach.

Comment: "if not i.endswith('.')" is not sufficient here. Presumably OP wouldn't want words with a period in the middle of them either, and endswith won't pick that up. Plus it sounds like he would want to ignore words ending with other non-alphanumeric characters besides periods.

Comment: @Sweater-Baron: point taken. Updated answer to account for periods. If he wants to ignore other non-alphanumeric characters he can edit the question.